# How to find specific artifacts using aql and jfrog cli

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli, artifactory-query-lang

I want to find all the artifacts that contain specific pattern,
except of few.

My `aql.json`

```
items.find({
    "name":{"$match": "*test*"},
    "name":{"$nmatch": "*test1*"},
    "name":{"$nmatch": "*test2*"}
   })
```

and I get this error:

```
[Error] invalid character 'i' looking for beginning of value
```

My jfrog cli cmd:

```
jfrog rt s --spec=aql.json
```

(I alredy config my artifactory with admin user on my linux env)

EDIT `aql.json`

```
{
    "files" :  [
        {
            "aql" : {
                "items.find" :{
                    "repo": "myRepo",
                    "path" : {"$match": "*/somedir/somedir*"},
                    "$and" : 
                    [
                        {"name" : {"$match" : "*test*"}},
                        {"name" : {"$nmatch" : "*test1*"}},
                        {"name" : {"$nmatch" : "*test2*"}}

                    ]

                }
            }
        } 
    ]
}
```

But it didn't find my artifacts (and I have artifacts that match this pattern.

```
[Info] Found 0 artifacts.
[]
```

Answer (score 4):

It expects to get a JSON.
This one worked for me:

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "aql": {
        "items.find": {
          "$and": [
            { "name": { "$match": "*test*" } },
            { "name": { "$nmatch": "*test_1*" } },
            { "name": { "$nmatch": "*test_2*" } }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: How to achieve .include("stat") equivalent in json format ?

Comment: @MuhammadFaizan-Ul-Haq you can try adding `--include "stat"` to the JFrog CLI command.